# Program prints too many

Tags: java, programming-languages

`enter code here:

```
public static void printArray(String Team, String[] Member, int[] Score)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Member.length; i++)
        {
    System.out.printf("Winning team:"+Team+"\n"+Member[i]+":"+Score[i]);
        {
```

Hello! My program keeps outputting

Winning team: Blue
Fred:20
Winning team: Blue
Hilda: 24
Winning team: Blue
Pat: 51

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated I am a newbie to java programming!

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove

```
"Winning team"+Team+"\n"
```

from the for loop (put a print on the line right above). The rest can stay the same (except add `'+"\n"` after `Score[i]`) to loop over the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If your file `bowling.txt` looks like this

```
Fred Blue 20 Hilda Blue 24 Pat Blue 51
```

Then you can use java code like the following to read and output it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("bowling.txt"));

        String Team, Member;
        int teamw, teamb, Score;
        String[] blue_members = new String[3];
        String[] white_members = new String[3];
        int[] blue_scores = new int[3];
        int[] white_scores = new int[3];


        int b = 0;
        int w = 0;

        System.out.println(
                "This program reads the lines from the file bowling.txt to determine\n"
                        + "the winner of a bowling match.  The winning team, members and scores\n"
                        + "are displayed on the monitor.\n");


        while (fin.hasNext()) {

            Member = fin.next();
            Team = fin.next();
            Score = fin.nextInt();

            if (Team.equals("Blue")) {


                blue_members[b] = Member;
                blue_scores[b] = Score;


                b++;
            } else {
                white_members[w] = Member;
                white_scores[w] = Score;

                w++;
            }
        }

        if (sumArray(blue_scores) > sumArray(white_scores)) {
            printArray("Blue", blue_members, blue_scores);
        } else {
            printArray("White", white_members, blue_scores);
        }

        fin.close();

    }


    public static int sumArray(int[] Score) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Score.length; i++)
            sum += Score[i];
        return sum;
    }

    public static void printArray(String Team, String[] Member, int[] Score) {
        System.out.println("Winning team:" + Team+"\n");
        System.out.println("Player Score" +"\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < Member.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(Member[i] + ":" + Score[i] +"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
This program reads the lines from the file bowling.txt to determine
the winner of a bowling match.  The winning team, members and scores
are displayed on the monitor.

Winning team:Blue

Player Score

Fred:20
Hilda:24
Pat:51

Process finished with exit code 0
```